# Exclude repeating caption from list of tables

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, memoir

I'm trying to create a table consisting of a number of relatively large subtables spanning a couple of pages in length. As each subtable should have it's own descriptive subcaption and depending on the data being tabulated can have different columns, the best approach I can come up with is to use the capt-of package to repeat the main caption on each page, and mess about with the counters to number each tabular correctly. (See the example below.) Naturally this gives multiple entries for the table in the list of tables. I know that the normal approach to fixing this is to use the captionsetup command, however this would require me to import the caption package which won't work well with the memoir based template I need to use. Does anyone have an idea on how to work around this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newsubfloat{table}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\pagebreak
\section{Section 1}

\begin{center}
\begin{vplace}
\makebox[\textwidth]{
\begin{minipage}[c]{2\textwidth}
\centering
\captionof{table}{Benchmark test on wavy bowl function, difficulty 10.\label{tab:benchWavyBowld10}}
\subtop[Benchmark methods]{
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{|c}}
\multirow{2}{*}{Method} & Avg. fevals & Avg. fevals & \multirow{2}{*}{Succ. Rate.} & \multirow{2}{*}{Best min.} & \multirow{2}{*}{Avg. min.} & \multirow{2}{*}{Worst min.}\\
 & (pre) & (post) & & & & \\
\hline
\hline
Steepest Descent & 1314 & 1197 & 8\% & 0.7651 & 30.15 & 156.6\\
BFGS & 696 & 935 & 4\% & 0.7651 & 49.20 & 275.3\\
CG & 1297 & 1453 & 4\% & 0.7651 & 64.83 & 196.2\\
\end{tabular}}
\subtop[Tunneling method with 100 iterations]{
\begin{tabular}{l*{8}{|c}}
\multirow{2}{*}{$\beta$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$m$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$R$} & Avg. fevals & Avg. fevals & \multirow{2}{*}{Succ. Rate.} & \multirow{2}{*}{Best min.} & \multirow{2}{*}{Avg. min.} & \multirow{2}{*}{Worst min.}\\
& & & (pre) & (post) & & & & \\
\hline
\hline
\multirow{9}{*}{1} & \multirow{3}{*}{0.01} & 0.5 & 311 & 311 & 7\% & 0.7651 & 37.38 & 147.2\\
& & 1 & 312 & 320 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 38.24 & 147.2\\
& & 5 & 313 & 322 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 39.95 & 147.2\\
\cline{2-9}
& \multirow{3}{*}{0.1} & 0.5 & 305 & 307 & 7\% & 0.7651 & 32.04 & 168.7\\
& & 1 & 306 & 300 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 31.89 & 168.6\\
& & 5 & 307 & 300 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 32.10 & 168.6\\
\cline{2-9}
& \multirow{3}{*}{1} & 0.5 & 304 & 312 & 9\% & 0.7651 & 43.67 & 174.9\\
& & 1 & 304 & 309 & 9\% & 0.7651 & 42.15 & 174.9\\
& & 5 & 304 & 310 & 9\% & 0.7651 & 42.00 & 174.9\\
\cline{1-9}
\multirow{9}{*}{1.2} & \multirow{3}{*}{0.01} & 0.5 & 311 & 315 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 38.45 & 147.2\\
& & 1 & 312 & 320 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 39.12 & 147.2\\
& & 5 & 313 & 322 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 39.95 & 147.2\\
\cline{2-9}
& \multirow{3}{*}{0.1} & 0.5 & 305 & 307 & 7\% & 0.7651 & 31.95 & 168.6\\
& & 1 & 306 & 300 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 31.92 & 168.6\\
& & 5 & 307 & 300 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 32.10 & 168.6\\
\cline{2-9}
& \multirow{3}{*}{1} & 0.5 & 303 & 313 & 7\% & 0.7651 & 44.77 & 174.9\\
& & 1 & 304 & 309 & 9\% & 0.7651 & 42.51 & 174.9\\
& & 5 & 304 & 310 & 9\% & 0.7651 & 42.00 & 174.9\\
\cline{1-9}
\multirow{9}{*}{1.5} & \multirow{3}{*}{0.01} & 0.5 & 310 & 315 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 40.47 & 147.2\\
& & 1 & 311 & 320 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 39.95 & 147.2\\
& & 5 & 313 & 322 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 39.95 & 147.2\\
\cline{2-9}
& \multirow{3}{*}{0.1} & 0.5 & 305 & 304 & 7\% & 0.7651 & 32.34 & 168.7\\
& & 1 & 305 & 300 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 32.47 & 168.6\\
& & 5 & 307 & 300 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 32.10 & 168.6\\
\cline{2-9}
& \multirow{3}{*}{1} & 0.5 & 303 & 312 & 7\% & 0.7651 & 44.80 & 174.9\\
& & 1 & 304 & 308 & 9\% & 0.7651 & 42.42 & 174.9\\
& & 5 & 304 & 310 & 9\% & 0.7651 & 42.00 & 174.9\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{minipage}}
\end{vplace}
\end{center}

\addtocounter{table}{-1}
\pagebreak
\begin{center}
\begin{vplace}
\makebox[\textwidth]{
\begin{minipage}[c]{2\textwidth}
\centering
\captionof{table}{Benchmark test on wavy bowl function, difficulty 10.}
\addtocounter{subtable}{2}
\subtop[Tunneling method with 500 iterations]{
\begin{tabular}{l*{8}{|c}}
\multirow{2}{*}{$\beta$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$m$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$R$} & Avg. fevals & Avg. fevals & \multirow{2}{*}{Succ. Rate.} & \multirow{2}{*}{Best min.} & \multirow{2}{*}{Avg. min.} & \multirow{2}{*}{Worst min.}\\
& & & (pre) & (post) & & & & \\
\hline
\hline
\multirow{9}{*}{1} & \multirow{3}{*}{0.01} & 0.5 & 311 & 311 & 7\% & 0.7651 & 37.38 & 147.2\\
& & 1 & 312 & 320 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 38.24 & 147.2\\
& & 5 & 313 & 322 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 39.95 & 147.2\\
\cline{2-9}
& \multirow{3}{*}{0.1} & 0.5 & 305 & 307 & 7\% & 0.7651 & 32.04 & 168.7\\
& & 1 & 306 & 300 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 31.89 & 168.6\\
& & 5 & 307 & 300 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 32.10 & 168.6\\
\cline{2-9}
& \multirow{3}{*}{1} & 0.5 & 304 & 312 & 9\% & 0.7651 & 43.67 & 174.9\\
& & 1 & 304 & 309 & 9\% & 0.7651 & 42.15 & 174.9\\
& & 5 & 304 & 310 & 9\% & 0.7651 & 42.00 & 174.9\\
\cline{1-9}
\multirow{9}{*}{1.2} & \multirow{3}{*}{0.01} & 0.5 & 311 & 315 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 38.45 & 147.2\\
& & 1 & 312 & 320 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 39.12 & 147.2\\
& & 5 & 313 & 322 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 39.95 & 147.2\\
\cline{2-9}
& \multirow{3}{*}{0.1} & 0.5 & 305 & 307 & 7\% & 0.7651 & 31.95 & 168.6\\
& & 1 & 306 & 300 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 31.92 & 168.6\\
& & 5 & 307 & 300 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 32.10 & 168.6\\
\cline{2-9}
& \multirow{3}{*}{1} & 0.5 & 303 & 313 & 7\% & 0.7651 & 44.77 & 174.9\\
& & 1 & 304 & 309 & 9\% & 0.7651 & 42.51 & 174.9\\
& & 5 & 304 & 310 & 9\% & 0.7651 & 42.00 & 174.9\\
\cline{1-9}
\multirow{9}{*}{1.5} & \multirow{3}{*}{0.01} & 0.5 & 310 & 315 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 40.47 & 147.2\\
& & 1 & 311 & 320 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 39.95 & 147.2\\
& & 5 & 313 & 322 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 39.95 & 147.2\\
\cline{2-9}
& \multirow{3}{*}{0.1} & 0.5 & 305 & 304 & 7\% & 0.7651 & 32.34 & 168.7\\
& & 1 & 305 & 300 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 32.47 & 168.6\\
& & 5 & 307 & 300 & 6\% & 0.7651 & 32.10 & 168.6\\
\cline{2-9}
& \multirow{3}{*}{1} & 0.5 & 303 & 312 & 7\% & 0.7651 & 44.80 & 174.9\\
& & 1 & 304 & 308 & 9\% & 0.7651 & 42.42 & 174.9\\
& & 5 & 304 & 310 & 9\% & 0.7651 & 42.00 & 174.9\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{minipage}}
\end{vplace}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
 \renewcommand\addcontentsline[3]{}
```

to locally disable this before your repeated captions.